# Task scheduler task not executing ps1 scripts

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to run a ps1 file in the Task scheduler.
The task should run every day in the evening and history shows that it has run,

[image: Task scheduler log image]

but not really because I can see in SonarQube that it did not.

Every individual step works as intended and if I run the action and command everything is fine:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\sonarqube\run_sonar_scan.ps1
```

And I also tried using the full path to powershell

The task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2020-07-27T13:10:30.3806911</Date>
    <Author>xxx\yyy</Author>
    <Description>Starts the SonarScanner bat files from run_sonar_scan.ps1</Description>
    <URI>\DdDRetail\SonarScanner</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2020-07-27T21:00:00</StartBoundary>
      <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT4H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-18</UserId>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>false</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT8H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
    <RestartOnFailure>
      <Interval>PT1M</Interval>
      <Count>3</Count>
    </RestartOnFailure>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>powershell.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\sonarqube\run_sonar_scan.ps1"</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

The ps1 file:

```
$repo_file_path="C:\Users\xxx\source\repos"

Start-Process "cmd.exe"  "/c $repo_file_path\run_articleservice_scan.bat"
```

The bat file

- updates a local repo from github
- updates Nuget packages
- runs a SonarScanner

Comment: I found out that using the "Run whether the user is logged on or not" prevented the execution. When unchecking the task runs just fine.
- Now on to the IT department and get the required permission on my user.

Answer (score 0):

The user needed to be either an administrator or having permissions to Run whether the user is logged on or not. User was changed to Administrator, all is fine and the task is executed as expected.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.